# Creating a contract at address in web3 pre-beta?

Tags: web3js

I know the web3 beta version way to create a contract is

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([abi], 'createAtAddress'});
```

However, I want to use a stable version of web3 and I've been using

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var myContract = web3.eth.contract([abi])
var contractInstance = myContract.at('0x486351a2b3f3f63c04aeec19281cc7293cab8337');
```

However with this, I can only interact with a preexisting contract. How can I create a new contract at a certain address?

The docs say

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.new({from: 'createAtAddress, gas: 1000000});
```

but for some reason that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data` part when calling `new`. So the actual code of the contract is not known when you try to create the contract. Try this:

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.new({from: 'createAtAddress, gas: 1000000, data: contractcode});
```

where `contractcode` ist the hex string containing the opcodes of your contract code that is returned after compiling.

See also [the JavaScript-API documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract)